How to run a stored procedure at the start of taskflow and after taskflow completed in informatica?
I created mappings and taskflow (informatica cloud) to insert data in a table but want to add sql command(stored procedure)at the start of taskflow and at the end of taskflow. Please help how to use stored procedures as single command in taskflow.
Thanks.

Hi - i believe this is covered in the documentation here: https://docs.informatica.com/integration-cloud/cloud-data-integration/current-version/transformations/sql-transformation/unconnected-sql-transformations/invoking-a-stored-procedure-before-or-after-a-mapping-run.html What’s the specific issue you are facing?
